# Getting 403 error when trying to add with admin user in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring Security in my web application and have implemented API permissions using the HttpSecurity configuration. When I try to add a new brand with an admin user, I get a 403 error. I have checked my database and verified that the endpoint and role are correct.

Here's the relevant code in my configuration class:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors();
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    List<ApiPermissions> permissions = permissionRepository.findAll();
    for (ApiPermissions permission : permissions) {
        String urlPattern = permission.getEndpoint();
        String httpMethod = permission.getMethod();
        String roleName = permission.getRole();
        if (roleName.equals(Role.ADMIN.name())) {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(httpMethod, urlPattern).hasRole(Role.ADMIN.name());
        } else if (roleName.equals(Role.USER.name())) {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(httpMethod, urlPattern).hasRole(Role.USER.name());
        } else {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(httpMethod, urlPattern).permitAll();
        }
    }

    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

I have also checked the logs and found the following entry :

this log when I run the app

> 2023-04-18 16:44:30.363 DEBUG 12128 --- [           main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')] for Ant [pattern='api/brands']

when am trying to add using admin user

> 2023-04-18 16:42:59.563 DEBUG 7080 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [POST /api/brands] with attributes [authenticated]

I have checked my database and the endpoint and role are correct. I have also checked my code and it seems to be correctly configured to allow admin users to access the "/api/brands" endpoint with the role "ROLE_ADMIN". I'm not sure what could be causing this issue.

Comment: The log message is clear: your user doesn't have the role `ROLE_ADMIN`. Show your user with roles.